# How to prevent window resize when exiting Target Display Mode

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, thunderbolt-display, target-display

Using a macbook pro, with a thunderbolt cable connecting to an iMac,
and using Target Display Mode [TDM] to mirror the display. I choose
the optimal resolution for the external display, which means more
pixels than I have when using the native display. (This is the
point. :)

When the iMac is disconnected (using cmd-F2 to exit TDM), the windows
all get resized and moved so they fit in the lower resolution
screen. I do not want this behavior. I carry my laptop back and forth
to work, and have several Mission Control workspaces that are used for
work only. Whenever I come in to work and connect to the big display,
I have to resize and move the windows back to where they were.

Is there any way to disable this resizing behavior? TIA